# Can we have a @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relationship between two tables in hibernate?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

Eg.

```
public class Portfolio implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "PORTFOLIO_OWNER", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK__USER__PORTFOLIO"), nullable = false)
    private User portfolioOwner;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_CAPTAIN", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK__USER__PORTFOLIO2"))
    private User accountCaptain;

}
```

and

```
public class User {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PORTFOLIO_ID", referencedColumnName = "PORTFOLIO_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_DEF_PORTFOLIO_USER"))
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Portfolio defaultPortfolio;

}
```

I run into Stackoverflow on fetching them using JACKSON as a JSON

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
>   (through reference chain:
>   com.User["defaultPortfolio"]->com..Portfolio["portfolioOwner"]->com.User["defaultPortfolio"]->com.Portfolio["portfolioOwner"]->com..User["defaultPortfolio"]-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add json ignore to one side of the relations ex:

```
public class Portfolio implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "PORTFOLIO_OWNER", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK__USER__PORTFOLIO"), nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User portfolioOwner;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_CAPTAIN", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK__USER__PORTFOLIO2"))
    private User accountCaptain;

}
```